# Web Control That Represents Dynamic Tape Measure

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

An exhaustive Google search has surprisingly pulled up no results. The closest that I've come is here: [Ux Input](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10256/whats-the-best-and-most-intuitive-way-to-have-a-user-enter-a-height-value-in-fe)

I am looking for a dynamic tape measure control for web... I believe I have seen this somewhere before... but in my minds eye it is basically a slider control. Something that would work well in mobile environments... basically you can just slide an infinite tape measure to where you need it... it then captures the values and converts fractions to decimals. Does a tool like this exist?

The only alternative besides creating it myself would be to do a series of drop downs... but this seems really clunky. Any further suggestions? Thanks for your help with this!

**Clarification:** I develop for a manufacturing company and am looking for a new way to enter in measurements on a mobile device.

Comment: I found a JSFiddle that you might be able to modify: https://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/t5Kts/ -- It calculates the distance from the mouse cursor to a point on the screen. But it may not be ideal for mobile environments. Can you tell us a little bit more on what the objective is? Might help in locating a more suitable solution.

Comment: @I.R.R. Sorry, I probably wasn't clear in my description. I am actually looking for a way that users can input values. I develop for a manufacturing company and am looking for a new way to enter in measurements on a mobile device.